# std::align not supported by g++4.9

Tags: c++, c++11, alignment

While learning about alignment issues etc, I realized that my implementation of g++4.9 (macports OS X) does not have support for `std::align`. If I try to compile (with `-std=c++11`) this example code from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/align/

```
// align example
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
  char buffer[] = "------------------------";
  void * pt = buffer;
  std::size_t space = sizeof(buffer) - 1;
  while ( std::align(alignof(int), sizeof(char), pt, space) ) {
    char* temp = static_cast<char*>(pt);
    *temp = '*'; ++temp; space -= sizeof(char);
    pt = temp;
  }
  std::cout << buffer << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

the compiler spits out the error

```
error: 'align' is not a member of 'std'
```

This seems strange as g++ seems to have implemented alignment support since g++4.8,  https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html (N2341)

The code compiles under clang++ without any problems.

Is this a well known issue of g++ that I am not aware of? The online compilers that I tested (ideone and coliru) reject the code also.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this is a known missing feature for gcc :

- [Bug 53814](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57350) : `std::align` missing

Comment: Thanks for the link, just saw that it didn't make it in g++4.9 trunk, although the bug was reported more than a year ago.

Comment: @vsoftco, "g++4.9 trunk" doesn't make sense. There is no "g++4.9 trunk". There is the 4.9 branch, and there is the trunk, which is a different branch.  The fix was made to the trunk. The Target Milestone field in the bug report says it will be in GCC 5.0

Comment: @JonathanWakely finally got it :)

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you could write your own alignment code that matches the behavior of `std::align`. The next piece of code is written by David Krauss in a post found here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57350

```
inline void *align( std::size_t alignment, std::size_t size,
                void *&ptr, std::size_t &space ) {
    std::uintptr_t pn = reinterpret_cast< std::uintptr_t >( ptr );
    std::uintptr_t aligned = ( pn + alignment - 1 ) & - alignment;
    std::size_t padding = aligned - pn;
    if ( space < size + padding ) return nullptr;
    space -= padding;
    return ptr = reinterpret_cast< void * >( aligned );
}
```

Comment: Beware that the line `auto new_space = space - ( aligned - pn );` is a potential unsigned underflow. The mentioned link provides the corrected version as well.