# Does std::bitset guarantee continious memory along with constant size in a structure (to avoid padding?)

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures, bitset

if I have a structure:

```
struct foo
{
    int ibar;
    std::bitset<32> bsbar;
    float fbar;
};
```

does bitset guarantee there will be no padding bytes between `ibar` and `bsbar` and that the size of this struct will always be `12` (for use in memcpy operations)?

Comment: `bitset` or not, the answer to the question "is it guaranteed to have X padding bytes" is always no. The implementation is allowed to add padding bytes for any or no reason, on a whim, so long as the alignment requirements hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and you should first test and see what the answer may be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>

struct foo
{
    int ibar;
    std::bitset<32> bsbar;
    float fbar;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::cout << sizeof(foo) << std::endl; // 24 on my machine (OS X 10.10 g++4.9.2 64 bit) 
}
```

Comment: But it comes out as 12 on at [least one platform](http://ideone.com/Oa7TYX).  So if that's the platform you're testing on, it wouldn't help at all with identifying what the general case is.

Comment: I am just saying that the response to "will always be 12" is negative, nothing more. As @T.C. mentioned, the compiler is allowed to do padding, unless you specifically specify the alignment.

Comment: @vsoftco you mean by #pragma pack?

Comment: @Gizmo, I use `clang++` with C++11 support, and I think you can specify the alignment with `std::align`, according to the standard. PS: `g++`, although claims it is fully C++11-compatible w.r.t. alignment, does not yet implement `std::align`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27064791/3093378 I think `@pragma pack` is also supported by `g++` (sure for `gcc`), but cannot bet my life on it.

Comment: GCC trunk supports `std::align`, but you can't use it to specify alignment. Maybe you're thinking of `alignas`

Comment: @JonathanWakely, then what is the role of it? I tried the code in the example I posted in the link above, and `g++` fails to compile it. AFAIK, `std::align` is just not implemented in `g++`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57350

Comment: Erm, look at the status of the bug and look who committed the fix: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57350#c12 -- it was committed [last month](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57350#c12). `std::align` is for putting an object at the correct alignment inside a buffer, i.e. asking the compiler to align it correctly. That is completely different from _specifying_ the alignment. Pretty much the opposite.

Comment: @JonathanWakely, I saw that, but try to compile and run the example, I'll send you a beer if it compiles :) I tried on `g++4.9(0,1,2)` and it fails. I upgraded `g++` last week from `macports` (g++4.9.2), and it fails.

Comment: I clearly said **GCC trunk supports `std::align`**. You are not using a build from the SVN trunk. All you can show is that 4.9.2 doesn't support it, but I'm telling you GCC trunk does support it, **because I committed the implementation!**

Comment: @JonathanWakely ok, I just saw that you committed it, so I believe you :) However the latest common **distributions** do not seem to have upgraded the trunk. This is the error I get on `g++4.9.2`: `In function 'int main()': so.cpp:9:11: error: 'align' is not a member of 'std'
   while ( std::align(alignof(int),sizeof(char),pt,space) ) {`

Comment: Yes, **I know what GCC 4.9 does you can stop repeating it thank you**

Comment: @JonathanWakely I didn't intend to offend you in any way, I am just saying that for the end user it is not altogether clear that `std::align` was implemented. When you look at N2341 in `https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html` it clearly says (before last month) that `gcc` fully supports it, which was not the case unless you compile `gcc` from source. And btw I didn't find the bugzilla page when searching for missing `std::align` (although now it is indexed).

Comment: That page does **not** say it's implemented, because that page doesn't  cover the standard library, see under the table where it says  "The status of the library implementation can be tracked in this [table](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.200x)" and there 20.6.5 says it is implemented. On the other hand, the [library status table for 4.9.2](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011) says N.

Comment: @JonathanWakely ok, got it, I just misunderstood that `align` support was referring just to the standard language support for `alignas/alignof` keywords. Thanks for the clarifications.

Answer (score 1):

Within a class, there may be unnamed padding between any member that occupies whole memory locations, the only exception being the first member of a standard-layout struct:

> If a standard-layout class object has any non-static data members, its
>   address is the same as the address of its first non-static data
>   member. Otherwise, its address is the same as the address of its first
>   base class subobject (if any). [ *Note:* There might therefore be
>   unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its
>   beginning, as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. — *end note*
>   ]

Implementations allow you to "pack" structs via Pragmas or compiler flags. GCC recognizes the [`pack` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Type-Attributes.html).